# React-Scripts import Bootstrap not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, webpack, react-scripts

I'm using React-Script and I have a button (Popover) in my React component 
But It's not working. I know that React-Bootstrap is available but I'm not allowed to use it :(

In React-Script docs they said:
https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-bootstrap

But they don't point out about import bootstrap.js

I have installed jquery + bootstrap from npm

Here is my Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "block-ui": "^2.70.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "history": "^4.6.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "1.0.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start"
  }
}
```

Here is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import UserProfile from './components/common/UserProfile';

import Routes from './routes';
import Navigator from './components/common/Navigator';

import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js';

// Global
global.config = require('./config');

// Navigator
ReactDOM.render(<Navigator />, document.getElementById('navigator'));

// Main
let browserHistory = createBrowserHistory()
ReactDOM.render(
    <Routes history={browserHistory} />,
    document.getElementById('main')
);
// Header
ReactDOM.render(<UserProfile />, document.getElementById('user_profile'));

registerServiceWorker();
```

Here is my React Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import jQuery from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js';

class CommonComment extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {}
    this.handle =                   this.handle.bind(this);
  }

  handle(event) {
    jQuery("#QQQ").popover('show');
  }

  }
  render() {
    var this2 = this;
    return (
      <div>
          <button id="QQQ" onClick={this2.handle} type="button" className="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export {CommonComment};
```

When I clicked on that button it show:

> TypeError:
>   __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_jquery___default(...)(...).popover is not a function

So I think Bootstrap is not included properly. Can someone point out where I did wrong.

---

New!
Docs Project-Structure
https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#folder-structure

Here is my project structure

[image]

Many thanks!!!

Comment: have you tried using react-bootstrap instead?
there's the popover component for react there.
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#overlays

Comment: I wish I could, my boss's not allowed :(, He said it's too heavy

Comment: then make sure you load the jquery on webpack using `ProvidePlugin`

`new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery'
})`

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/

Comment: Thanks, but where am I supposed to put these lines?

Comment: on the webpack config, you should have a file called `webpack.config.js` on your root folder.

Comment: I don't think I have that option, please see my project structure in question

Comment: ah, I see that you build your react using react-create-app, in that case, you have to eject the config, and edit them manually. remember that, once you eject, you can't go back. :) 
https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#converting-to-a-custom-setup